# Get message ID in Azure queue

Tags: azure

Is there a way to get the message ID after insert it in a queue Azure ?

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = 
    CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.createCloudQueueClient();

CloudQueue queue = queueClient.getQueueReference("myqueue");

queue.createIfNotExist();

CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage("Hello, World");
queue.addMessage(message);

// Get message ID here ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way you could get the message id is `by getting the message`. So you would have to fetch messages from the queue using `GetMessage` or `GetMessages` method. However there's no guarantee that you will get the message you just created as `GetMessages` can only return up to 32 visible messages from the top of the queue.

Comment: So I need to put an unique ID directly in the message content if I want to get it later ?

Comment: You could do that but you can't tell queue service to return you that particular message. What you have to do is get the messages, iterate over them and find the relevant message. If searching by id is critical for you, you may want to look at table storage. Though you will need to handle concurrency issues yourself. Another option could be to use Service Bus Queues. Since I have not worked with them at all, I am not sure if it supports fetching message by id. But you may want to check it out.

Comment: And I want to update a message. How does it work if I can't get message ID ?

Comment: To update a message, you would need message id. Without that, you can't update the message. Thus your only option would be to get messages using `GetMessages`, iterate over them to find the message you wish to update and update that message. HTH.

Comment: I think an important question is why you would want to update an already queued message?

Answer (score 7):

I realize it has been 5 years since this was originally asked; however, it is now possible to achieve this.

```
CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage("Hello, World");
queue.AddMessage(message);

// here's how you get the id
string id = message.Id;
```

Comment: thanks for coming and updating this .

Answer (score 0):

Since queue lies on the principle "First In First Out" or FIFO, that is why you can't just get the particular message anytime you want but you have to use the GetMessage and iterate on it.