# Get messageId of message sent to Azure queue with .NET v12 SDK

Tags: .net, azure, sdk, azure-storage-queues

How can I get the `messageId` of a message I send to a queue using .NET v12?

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56407472/11636360 in [Get message ID in Azure queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949442/get-message-id-in-azure-queue) shows how it can be done in .NET v11, but .NET v12 `SendMessage` method only accepts a string input.

Here's a code snippet from [Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues?tabs=dotnet#insert-a-message-into-a-queue) to put a message in a queue using .NET v12.

Cycling through `PeekMessages` afterwards and look for a message with the same content is all I can think of but doesn't seem very neat or would necessarily work with a large number of messages in the queue.

```
// Get the connection string from app settings
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"];

// Instantiate a QueueClient which will be used to create and manipulate the queue
QueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(connectionString, queueName);

// Create the queue if it doesn't already exist
queueClient.CreateIfNotExists();

if (queueClient.Exists())
{
    // Send a message to the queue
    queueClient.SendMessage(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SendMessage` method returns an object of type `Response<SendReceipt>`. Looking at the documentation for [`SendReceipt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.queues.models.sendreceipt?view=azure-dotnet), you should be able to get the message id from its `MessageId` property.

Please try something like:

```
if (queueClient.Exists())
{
    // Send a message to the queue
    var response = queueClient.SendMessage(message);
    var messageId = response.Value.MessageId;
}
```